# HTML5 Geolocation - Detect location within a specific area

Tags: html, geolocation

I haven't had much of an opportunity to look at HTML5 Geolocation yet, but I'm curious: Is it possible to build a web app that can detect when a user enters a certain area (perimeter) and then return a message or something like that?

Comment: You mean like a live GPS thing? You can only grab coordinates from one location at a time, and your user has to grant access.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking following a user's location and showing messages depending where they are. Doesn't maps.google.com do this (as in follow you live) on the iPhone/Android?

Comment: Yeah, but you can't access those APIs from a web app (or from a regular app, for that matter). Sorry. What you could do is check location upon launch of your web app and then return a message. And then set an interval of checking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `watchPosition` to get periodic updates of the browser's location, and then in your callback, test to see if the new position is within your area of interest. So if you've defined a function `isInArea` that checks a position to see if it's in your area of interest, you could do something like:

```
function positionCallback(position) {
  if (isInArea(position)) {
    alert("Honey, I'm home!");
  }
}

function handleError(error) {
  alert("Error!")
}

// Request repeated updates.
var watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(positionCallback, handleError);
```

Based on *Example of requesting repeated position updates* from [w3c](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html).